# In ExtJs what kind of object is returned by form.getValues

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following code which I got directly from a tutorial in ExtJs:

```
updateUser: function (button) {
var win = button.up('window'),
form = win.down('form'),
record = form.getRecord(),
values = form.getValues();

record.set(values);
win.close();
```

Now, I am working on some modifications to suit my needs, what exactly do the following 3 lines return:

```
form = win.down('form'),
record = form.getRecord(),
values = form.getValues();
```

According to the documentation, the `down()` method above returns an `Ext.Container.AbstractContainer` that should not even be used according to the documentation. Furthermore, it does not have a `getRecord()` or a `getValues()` method. Can anyone explain what is going on here and what kind of objects those 2 calls return?

Comment: According to the documentation, a whole lot of classes (inluding `Ext.form.Panel`) are subclasses of `AbstractContainer`. So in and of itself `Window.down` returning it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `up` it looks for the ancestor of selector passed. When you call `down` it returns the descendant of the selector passed. `form.getRecord()` returns the model instance of the form. and `form.getValues()` returns the actual values entered in the form.

Ex: Model has 3 fields `id, name, email` and some config when you call `form.getRecord()` it returns the model instance, basically skeleton.

Where as `form.getValues()` returns the values entered.
Ex: If the following values are entered in the form `id=1, name=xxxxx,  email=aaaaa@test.com`
when you call `form.getValues()` it returns an object

```
{
  id:1,
  name:'xxxxx',
  email:'aaaaa@test.com'
}
```

I hope this answers you question

Comment: Thanks, I was actually able to partially figure out the answer with the help of `Ext.ClassManager.getName(record)` but your answer clarified everything.